# Partial match within MAP/ LAMBDA function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, match, spreadsheet, lookup

I have a formula that lookup data for a particular date and an ID.
My issue is some cells have multiple IDs. So I'm trying to find a way to look for a partial match within my formula.
Below is the formula I'm currently using.

```
=MAP(B2:B,C2:C,LAMBDA(bx,cx,IF(bx="",,IFNA(FILTER(FILTER(Data!B:G,EOMONTH(Data!B1:G1,0)=EOMONTH(INT(LEFT(cx,7)),0)),Data!A:A=bx)))))
```

I'm guessing the last part is the one that need to be changed ->

```
Data!A:A=bx
```

I usually use the below trick to get an approximate match, but it does not work in this case.

```
"*"Data!A:A"*" or "*"&Data!A:A&"*"
```

here is my sample for file to better undesrtand my issue:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxZYj5CTUuOjcVBeDC_v6nlizoPakNHRTpAZgrOahEw/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with REGEXMATCH to find the text no matter its location:

```
=MAP(B2:B,C2:C,LAMBDA(bx,cx,IF(bx="",,IFNA(FILTER(FILTER(Data!B:G,EOMONTH(Data!B1:G1,0)=EOMONTH(INT(LEFT(cx,7)),0)), REGEXMATCH (Data!A:A,bx))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, simpler than I thought it would be. Thanks a lot !